# Cast type with Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, rest, serialization, json.net

Before, i used IDataContractSurrogate for serializing my datas, but it's not compatible with CPL (portable class librairy), so i'm using Newtonsoft now.

But, i have to cast a ObservableCollection type to List with :

```
myobj [ { id:1, name="test1", value="test_1"}, { id:2, name="test2", value="test_2"}]
```

to `myobj ["test1", "test2"],`

Is it possible ? 
I tried like this :

```
public class ccrUser : DefaultContractResolver { // Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.IContractResolver

        private bool toSerialise;
        public static readonly ccrUser Instance = new ccrUser(true);

        /// <summary>Constructeur</summary>
        /// <param name="pToSerialise">Indique le sens qui sera utlisé (les API ne donnent pas le même format en GET qu'elles attendent en POST).</param>
        public ccrUser(bool pToSerialise) : base() { toSerialise = pToSerialise; }

        protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType) {
            var contract = base.CreateContract(objectType);
            if ((toSerialise) && (objectType == typeof(ObservableCollection<tblGroup>))) {
                //contract.Converter = new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.CustomCreationConverter<string>();
                return base.CreateArrayContract(objectType);
            } else
                return contract;
        }
        protected override List<MemberInfo> GetSerializableMembers(Type objectType) {
            var defaultMembers = base.GetSerializableMembers(objectType);
            if ((toSerialise) && (objectType == typeof(ObservableCollection<tblGroup>))) {
                return defaultMembers;
            } else
                return defaultMembers;
        }


        protected override JsonConverter ResolveContractConverter(Type objectType) {
            if (objectType == typeof(ObservableCollection<tblGroup>)) {
                return null; // pretend converter is not specified
            }
            return base.ResolveContractConverter(objectType);
        }

        /// <summary>JSON value provider that always returns a static value</summary>
        public class StaticValueProvider : IValueProvider {
            private readonly object _staticValue;
            public StaticValueProvider(object staticValue) {  _staticValue = staticValue; }
            public void SetValue(object target, object value) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
            public object GetValue(object target) { return _staticValue; }
        }

        protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization) {
            JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
            if ((toSerialise) && (property.PropertyType == typeof(ObservableCollection<tblGroup>))) {
            }
            return property;
        }
    }
```

but can't find the solution.

Regards

Comment: Why don't you deserialize `myobj` as it is and then do something in getter of other property to return what you need? Or if the problem is opposite (to serialize), then serialize some other property (which does type conversion) instead of original one.

Comment: Because the collision of the name. In the serialization requires that "groups" it's an array of string and deserialization requires that "groups" it is an array of objects .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of casting during serialization/deserialization process itself you can serialize/deserialize another property (of another type):

```
// serialize only marked members
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class SerializableObject
{
    // original property: not serialized
    public TypeA PropertyA { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(nameof(PropertyA))]
    public TypeB PropertyB
    {
        get
        {
            // convert PropertyA value to TypeB
            return (TypeB)PropertyA;
        }
        set
        {
            // convert TypeB to TypeA and set PropertyA value
            PropertyA = (TypeA)value;
        }
    }
}
```

`PropertyB` (can be `private` if you like) is only used to serialize/deserialize `PropertyA` value as another type.

Comment: This works, but i think it's not beautuful :
        [DataMember(Name ="groups")]
        public IEnumerable<object> groupsApi {
            get { return (_groups!=null)? (from c in (ObservableCollection<tblGroup>)_groups select c.value).ToList():null; }
            set { _groups = new ObservableCollection<tblGroup>();
                value.ForEach((a) => { _groups.Add(((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)a).ToObject<tblGroup>()); }) ;
            }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<tblGroup> groups { get { return _groups; } set { _groups = value; } }

Answer (score 0):

There is a compilation error, it can't parse List < string > to IEnumerable < tblGroup > :

```
    [DataMember(Name ="groups")] 
public List<string> groupsApi { get { return (from c in (ObservableCollection<tblGroup>)_groups select c.value).ToList(); } set { _groups = new ObservableCollection<tblGroup>(value); } } 
public ObservableCollection<tblGroup> groups { get { return _groups; } set { _groups = value; } }
```